# How to retrieve all the tables from an sql linked server

Tags: sql, linked-server

I have an sql linked server whose data I can access using openquery, but I have no idea of how to see the tables of that database, hence i cant do much.

I only have a query

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSERVER, 'SELECT * FROM SERVXML.DATA AS A WHERE A.DATAID = 2355')
```

Which returns some stuff.

But otherwise how can I see all the info in MYSERVER? I mean all the tables more specifically.

I have tried using this

```
EXEC sp_tables_ex 'MYSERVER';
```

With no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused.  If you have a linked server, then you can just access the tables using a four-part naming convention:  ...table.

This is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

You can see the linked servers using metadata tables and views.  For instance:

```
select *
from <server>.<database>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```